# NSDateFormatter not formatting correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I think I am using the NSDateFormatter in a wrong way. I have a UIDatePicker. When I select a date, my day label ,month label, year label and time label is set.

When I click on a save button I build up a date with this labels and send it to my server.
I do it like this.

```
 NSString *dateStringBegin = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@",lblBeginDay.text,lblBeginMonth.text,lblBeginYear.text,lblBeginTime.text];

//LOG dateStringBegin =  7 februari 2013 11:21
```

But my server only accepts a string that looks like this `2013-02-07 11:21`

Now I am doing this in code.

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d MMMM YYYY hh:mm"];
    NSDate* date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStringBegin];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat2 setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"];
    NSString *dateStringBegin2 =  [dateFormat2 stringFromDate:date];
```

Now when I look at how my dateStringBegin2 looks like, I see this.

```
//LOG dateStringBegin2 = 2013-12-28 11:21
```

Comment: http://iphoneappcode.blogspot.in/2012/08/nsdateformatter-example-in-iphone-sdk.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code:-

```
NSString *dateStringBegin = @"7 february 2013 11:21";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm"];
    NSDate* date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStringBegin];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
    NSString *dateStringBegin2 =  [dateFormat2 stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Date : %@",dateStringBegin2);
```

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d MMMM YYYY hh:mm"];
[dateFormat2 setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"];
```

To :

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d MMMM yyyy hh:mm"];
[dateFormat2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
```

The problem here is, yyyy uses to specify the year component. It's a common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the calendar year.

Answer (score 0):

change your date format to

```
[dateFormat2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
```